# WPF what is the default image source class when setting the source property on an image in xaml

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

So I was curious how the following line works.

```
  <Image Width="50" Source="/DaedalusGraphViewer;component/Images/images.jpg" 
         Stretch="Fill"/>
```

I assume that the source string is converted using a default converter to some sort of imagesource. However, imagesource is an abstract class, so I was wondering whether it converts to a bitmapsource or a drawingimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `BitmapFrameDecode (internal sealed class with BitmapFrame as base class)`, you can see that in debugger watch window by using `image.Source.GetType()` where `image` is `x:Name given to Image control` -

[image]

As @Clemens mentioned in comment that default conversion is done by [ImageSourceConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter.aspx) which internally calls [BitmapFrame.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616002.aspx) to return `BitmapFrameDecode`.

Comment: Also worth to note is that the default conversion is done by [ImageSourceConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter.aspx). Basically, it calls [BitmapFrame.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616002.aspx), which returns a BitmapFrameDecode.